# How can I properly set up my foreground service to work in background?

Tags: java, android, background, foreground-service

I've got a problem:

I tried many times to properly set up `foreground service` to work in background. Every time my `service` suspends after maybe one minute after turning off my phone screen. I tried `WakeLock`, triggering service events by a `timer` and by a `thread` inside this `service`.

Could you help me solving this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of the `foreground service` is not to do long running `background tasks`. It is for sometime to let the user know that your app is doing some work and the user is aware for that.

For doing any `background task`, you can check with [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) in Android JetPack Libraries. You can find below key features of WorkManager:

**Key features:**

- Backwards compatible up to API 14
- Uses JobScheduler on devices with API 23+
- Uses a combination of BroadcastReceiver + AlarmManager on devices with API 14-22
- Add work constraints like network availability or charging status
- Schedule asynchronous one-off or periodic tasks
- Monitor and manage scheduled tasks
- Chain tasks together
- Ensures task execution, even if the app or device restarts
- Adheres to power-saving features like Doze mode

I don't know what is your task to do. But, as per your question it seemed that you need to do any background task. So, I have shared little knowledge with you according to my understanding.